# Understanding Lang's proof that every closed and bounded set is compact

Tags: general-topology, complex-analysis, metric-spaces, proof-explanation, compactness

In his book Serge Lang provides the following proof that every bounded set that is closed is also compact.

" Let S be a closed and bounded set. This implies that there exists $B$ s.t. $|z|\leq B$ where $z\in s$. For all $z$ write $z=x+iy$, then $|x|\leq B$ and $|y| \leq B$.

Let ${z_n}$ be a sequence in $S$, and write $z_n=x_n+iy_n$.

There is a subsequence {$z_{n_1}$} s.t. {${x_{n_1}}$} converges to a real number $a$ and similarly  there is a subsequence {${z_{n_2}}$} s.t. {${y_{n_2}}$} converges to a real number $b$.

Then {$z_{n_2}= x_{n_2}+i{y_2}$} converges to $a+ib$ which implies that $S$ is compact."

What I don't understand is two things.

1. How does proving {$x_{n_1}$} converges to $a$ prove that {${x_{n_2}}$} converges to $a$ aswell?
2. How is it implied that there exist such subsequences such that {${x_{n_1}}$} and {${y_{n_2}}$} converge to these values? Afterall isn't this what we are suppose to prove?

If anybody could shine some light, I will greatly appreciate it.

Comment: Serge Lang wrote more than one book. :)

Comment: @CalumGilhooley to clarify this is his "Introduction to Complex Analysis at a graduate level"

Comment: Please, Remember Bolzano-Weierstrass theorem for real bounded sequences.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is indeed a mistake. You should take a convergent subsequence of $y_{n_1}$  which converges, not just a subsequence of $y_n$. In that case $x_{n_2}$ is a subsequence of $x_{n_1}$ and hence it converges to $a$ as well.

As for your second question, I believe the author assumes you already know that a bounded sequence of real numbers has a convergent subsequence (the Bolzano-Weierstrass theorem), and now he uses it to prove this property holds for complex sequences as well.

Comment: Thank you for the clarification. I guess it was just a typo but most importantly, I finally understand why he mentioned Theorem a couple of pages ago. Funnily enough, I was trying to prove it by relating it compact sets. Everything is now clear, thanks for the answer.

Comment: Also, @Mark I wanted to ask you if you know where the fact that $S$ is used in the proof by serge lang because he used it to show that a compact set and a set which is bounded  and closed are equivalent?

Comment: He used the fact that $S$ is bounded to show $(z_n)$ has a convergent subsequence, and since $S$ is closed the limit of this subsequence has to be in $S$ as well. This shows the set is compact-every sequence of elements in $S$ has a subsequence which converges to an element in $S$.

Comment: All clear, thank you!

Answer (score 3):

1. The sequence $\{x_{n_2}\}$ is a subsequence of the sequence $\{x_{n_1}\}$. Since $\{x_{n_1}\}$ converges to $a$, any of its subsequences also converges to $a$.
2. By the Bolzano-Weierstrass theorem, every bounded sequence of real numbers has a convergent subseqeunce.

Comment: Ah, I was wondering why he mentioned in a couple of pages ago. Interestingly enough I was trying to prove it by relating it to compact sets. Now I see that the theorem was a nessecaty in his equivalence proof between compact sets and sets which are bounded and closed at the same time. Thanks for the answer

Answer (score 0):

As $\mathbb{R}^2=\mathbb{C}$, we may proceed by noting that:

**Every closed and bounded set in $\mathbb{R}^2$ is compact.**

Here is a proof:

Let $F\subseteq \mathbb{R}^2$ be both, closed and bounded. Let $(x_n)_n\subseteq F$ be a sequence. As  $(x_n)_n$ is bounded, it follows from the Bolzano Weirstrass theorem that $(x_n)_n$ has a convergent subsequence, which converges to some $x\in \mathbb{R}^2$. As $F$ is closed, $x\in F$. $\square$